# jQuery validation -- exiting from a function

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to exit a function when a required input is not valid... but am having trouble. See below for code. Why doesn't the `return` work? I've also tried `return false` and `break` with no luck.

**Code:**

```
function SendTo(id){        

        ///////// VALIDATE & CLEAR INPUTS ////////////
        var elems = $('form').find('input');
        var arr = jQuery.makeArray(elems);

        jQuery.each(arr, function() {
            var input = $(this);

            //REQUIRED
            if (input.hasClass('required')) {
                if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.addClass('fail');
                    $('#messages .error').text('The above fields are required.', function() {
                        $(this).fadeIn('slow')
                    });
                    return;
                }

            }

            //CLEAR
            if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.val('[EMPTY]');
            }
        });
}
```

**EDIT:**

I got it working with the following code:

```
///////// VALIDATE & CLEAR INPUTS ////////////
        var allGood = true;

        $('form input').each(function() {
            var input = $(this);

            //REQUIRED
            if (input.hasClass('required')) {
                if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.addClass('fail');
                    $('#messages .error').text('The above fields are required.', function() {
                        $(this).fadeIn('slow')
                    });
                    allGood = false;
                }
            }
        });
        return allGood;
```

Comment: Are you sure `return false;` doesn't work? It works for me

Comment: Yeah... it skips right over it.

Comment: Then that's your logical problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you're doing jQuery.each.

Returing from that will just go to the next one. However, I'm pretty sure `return false;`, like Minum said should `break`, not `conintue`

From the website:

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.
>   http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 1):

```
function a(){
  $.each(b, c() {
   return;//return from each but NOT from function a)
  }
return;//returns from function a
}
```